# remove /public using .htaccess from domain.com/project/public

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, shared-hosting

**Remove /public using .htaccess from domain.com/project/public**

My project is in domain.com/project/ hosted in shared host and it is done in Symfony 5

when i want to access page i need to put /public in url.

What I tried here is the following in public_html/project folder and the .htaccess in /public as default:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

What I want here is I want to access url without /public like domain.com/project/ url, such that where ever I click on any other route domain.com/project/ must be as a base URL
eg.

```
 domain.com/project/about
 domain.com/project/list
 domain.com/project/contact
```

etc

Comment: I think that should be something like `public/index.php/$1` but apache Symfony pack can help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: I tried but didn't worked. if the files were in public_html dir then  it works because I have hosted couples of websites. Here in sub dir its not working. There is already website running in domain.com and the another website files has to put in domain.com/folder.